# Measuring negative pressure with a raspberry pi and I2C Pressure Sensor

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi, i2c, pressure

I want to measure negative pressure which is generated by a diaphragm / membrane pump with 0,5 Bar (according specification).

I am not sure if such a sensor as this https://sensing.honeywell.com/HSCDAND001BASA3-amplified-board-mount-pressure-sensors would work? Measuring range is from 0 to 1 bar. But my pump is generating negative pressure which I want to measure. Is this possible?

Can anybody help me please...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The linked sensor is an absolute pressure sensor.

Which means it is fine to use it, but the value you get might not be quite what you expect it to be.

As it measures the absolute pressure, it will measure against a close to total vacuum, your pump is working against air pressure. So to get the pressure of the pump, you have to store the pressure value before turning the pump on. Then turn the pump on and measure again. The difference between the two values is the pressure (or rather vacuum) your pump is generating.

For example, the current air pressure is 960 mbar. You will get a reading of 960 mbar from the sensor. Then you turn your pump and it will create some vacuum. The reading you get is then say 500 mbar. The vacuum your pump generates is then 960 mbar - 500 mbar = 460 mbar.

There are relative pressure sensors available which are rated for vacuum, which would make the task a bit easier. They are sometimes sold as vacuum sensors. A range would read like -1 to 1 bar or something like that. There you can use just the reading and don't have to calculate something.

Comment: Hi Arsenal, thanks for your good explanation and great answer. That helped me a lot to understand the issue. However, I can not find such a vacum or relative sensor with one input (for the hoch comming from my membrane pump) with i2c. Can you show me a cheap and good one, please? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: @user3352632 well, I'm not using any of these as I'm working in a company making pressure sensors (not cheap ones), but maybe [this Honeywell](https://www.digikey.de/product-detail/de/honeywell-sensing-and-productivity-solutions/SSCDANN015PD6A5/SSCDANN015PD6A5-ND/3934918) might work for you. You can also use a differential pressure sensor and leave one connection open as long as the range is okay.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply! I only can aquire such cheap sensor for my project. I done your second proposal: leave one free... thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 0):

The real question is,  the pressure range in the sensor's datasheet is absolute or relative pressure. As I see,  it is absolute. 
The relative scale is what we use mostly,  the 0 is the pressure measured at sea level. It is 1ATM (~1bar) on the absolute scale,  where 0 is full vacuum without any particles. The answer is yes,  you can measure vacuum with that sensor.

Answer (score 0):

Ostensibly, no, it won't work as it's not rated for vacuum, if itmeasures gage pressure.  That said, the pressure on one side is always greater than the pressure on the other, so if you measure atmospheric with respect to your vacuum, you're  measuring positive pressure, and get the info you need.  If you can't do that, shop for a sensor that can go in either direction.

This works if you're sensor measures gage pressure, and not absolute.  If it measures absolute, you're fine.